# Cannot make post requests with fetch() to any url

Tags: node.js, reactjs, post, fetch-api

I'm trying to send data from my frontend react application to my node backend, and whenever i make a post request with the fetch() function i get this error in the firefox dev tools console:

TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

I'm trying to post to http://localhost:8080/uploadComic, but i get the same error if I try to make a request to https://reqbin.com/post

When i make a request to http://localhost:8080/uploadComic using firefox dev tools, i get a response from the server, so I think my frontend code might be the problem

here is the frontend code:

```
handleSubmit = async () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/uploadComic', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({message: 'test'})
    }).then(data => {
      console.log(data)
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e)
    })
  }
```

and here is my backend code:

```
router.post('/uploadComic', function (req, res) {

    // this never prints
    console.log('/uploadComic: request recieved')
})
```

I have multiple GET requests to my backend using fetch() which all work fine, and i've tried to keep the code as simple as possible to at least try to get a response from the backend.

I'm sure it's probably a really simple fix but i've been stuck on this for awhile and can't seem to figure it out

**EDIT**

i found the problem, the `<form>` element in my html was causing the error. The data started posting after removing the `<form>` tags

Answer (score 0):

Try doing post request using axios.

```
const post = { message: 'test'}
    try {
      const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/users', post)
      console.log(res.data)
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e)
    }
```

I also checked your `fetch()` function code, your code is  working well. But for common practices and better error detection we write code like this :

```
 try {
              const response = await fetch(''http://localhost:8080/uploadComic', {
                headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
                method : 'POST',
                body : JSON.stringify({
                 message : 'test' 
                })
              })
             const data =await  response.json() 
             console.log(data)
            }catch(e){
                console.log(e)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, i managed to find the problem, it was with my html code. the `<form>` tags were breaking it